# keyup keydown methods NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I made an instance of NSViewController and added it as a subview to the main window's content view. I want to be able to capture keyboard events, but I have no idea how to implement it.After some research, I learned I needed to implement `acceptsFirstResponder` and the `keyUp:event:` and `keyDown:event:` methods in the NSViewController, but after that I still don't have the thing working.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    /* GViewController subview of NSViewController */
    GViewController *g = [[GViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GViewController" bundle:nil];
    [contentView addSubview: g];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those methods have to be present in a subclass of `NSView`, not `NSViewController`. It also doesn't make any sense to do `addSubview:someViewController`; the argument to that method needs to be a view.

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that, as opposed to window controllers, view controllers are not automatically added to the responder chain.

Comment: This isn't quite correct. NSViewController DOES implement acceptsFirstResponder, keyUp: and keyDown:. Both NSViewController and NSView are derived from NSResponder and it is NSResponder that these methods live on. However, it is correct that addSubview: should be given an NSView rather than the controller. And, as Bavarious notes, this will only work if the NSViewController has been added to the responder chain.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    super.keyDown(with: event)
    Swift.print("Caught a key down: \(event.keyCode)!") 
}
```

override keyDown with event worked for me in swift 
you can try same method in object-c.
check out offical doc
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1525805-keydown?language=objc